# Find second highest salary from a table with three coloumns Id, name, salary

Tags: mysql

How to find second highest salary from a table with three columns and these are **`id`**, **`name`**, **`salary`** but using in **`SELF JOIN`**.Got answer via **`nested query`**. but, I want to know how can we frame using **`SELF JOIN`**

Answer (score 0):

why join if you can do it using SELECT statement only?

**try this:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT salary FROM myTable ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT 1,1 ;
```

Comment: what if the two top entries have both the same salary?

Answer (score 0):

If you must use self join, you can do something like this...

```
SELECT x.val 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.val >= x.val 
 GROUP 
    BY x.val HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT y.val) = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

***Find second highest salary from a table with three coloumns Id, name, salary:***

```
SELECT id,NAME,salary FROM high
WHERE salary = (SELECT DISTINCT(salary) FROM high AS e1
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(salary))=2 FROM high AS e2
WHERE e1.salary <=e2.salary))
ORDER BY NAME;
```

***look at the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/99a14/1)***

***anthor one interesting answer:***

```
SELECT id,NAME,salary
FROM high 
WHERE salary = (SELECT DISTINCT(salary) 
                FROM high AS e1 
                WHERE id  = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(salary)) 
                             FROM high AS e2 
                             WHERE e1.salary <= e2.salary))
```